# Find $\lim_{x\rightarrow 0} \frac{(a+x)^x-a^x}{x^2}$ with $a>0$

Tags: calculus, limits

$$\lim_{x\rightarrow 0} \frac{(a+x)^x-a^x}{x^2}$$ with $a>0$

I think this relates to this

$$\lim_{h\rightarrow 0} \frac{f(x_0+h)-f(x_0)}{h}$$

But I can't find f(x) in this context. I think it might be $f(x) = a^x$ but that would mean that $f(x_0+h) = a^{x+h}$ or something, which doesn't make sense in this case.

Anyone know? The problem doesn't specify whether $a$ is a constant or a variable which is confusing me.

Comment: As far as your limit is concerned, $a$ is a constant.

Comment: can you use the rules of L'Hospital?

Comment: @Dr.SonnhardGraubner I'm not sure, I think so.

Comment: I got $0$. It seems strange enough.

Answer (score 3):

$$\lim_{x\to 0} \frac{(a+x)^x-a^x}{x^2}=
\lim_{x\to 0}\left(a^x \frac{(1+x/a)^x-1}{x^2}\right)=
\lim_{x\to 0}\left(a^x{e^{x\ln (1+x/a)}-1\over x\ln (1+x/a)}
\cdot{\ln (1+x/a)\over x/a}\cdot{1\over a}\right)={1\over a}.
$$

Comment: WHat did you do between steps 1 and two? How did you divide $(a+x)^x$ by $(a^x)$ if its between parathesis?

Comment: $$(a+x)^x/a^x=\left({a+x\over a}\right)^x=\left(1+{x\over a}\right)^x$$